# Export from fiddler to Postman

Tags: postman, fiddler

I am trying to simulate this in Postman. When you click the button it is opened in another window so I cant see the request in the developer network toolbar in Crome. However I can see it in Fiddler. The request look like this:

```
POST http://www.q88.com:8081/ws/API.asmx/GetHVPQQuestions_DataSet HTTP/1.1
Host: www.q88.com:8081
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 52
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://www.q88.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Referer: http://www.q88.com/ws/API.asmx?op=GetHVPQQuestions_DataSet
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,da-DK;q=0.8,da;q=0.7,und;q=0.6
Cookie: CompanyID=-1

AuthorizationString=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Now I would like that to be exported to Postman. However as I cannot get the curl from Crome, how do I add this raw request to Postman easily?

Answer (score 16):

#### To import headers

- Fiddler: File > Export Sessions > Selected Sessions... > cURL Script > Save as *.bat > Copy content of file
- Postman > Import > Raw Text > Paste copied text

#### To import body

- Fiddler > Inspectors > Raw > Copy content of last line
- Postman > Body > raw > Paste line

Comment: This does not work.  As explained in the other answer, the cURL format used by fiddler is not supported in Postman

Comment: The body of the export from fiddler is double url encoded.  Decoding that and removing the extra `%` allowed postman to import it

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above method and failed with Fiddler 4 and Postman v9.1.3. It cause `Error while importing Curl: URI malformed`

Change to

1. Download [FiddlerExportToPostman](https://github.com/bdrupieski/FiddlerExportToPostman/releases)
2. Unzip the two file to Fiddler root folder's subfolder, with the name of `ImportExport`
3. Restart Fiddler
4. Fiddler：Select what you want to export → File → Export Sessions → Selected Sessions... → Postman → Next → Save
5. Postman：Import → File → Choose the file you export